# JAVA algorithm in the background during GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, background

I have a problem, I can't crop up. I have to make a wild graphical interface where the buttons are enabled after a certain event or a certain action of a specific algorithm (like finite state machine).

I decided to make two classes, one for the GUI and the other is a thread that runs after the frame was created.

Now must wait until a message arrives on a socket, after which they must enable a button and then have to wait for you to press this button and enable two subsequently and so on.

Then I created static buttons in the Frame class that I go to enable / disable the appropriate thread.

this is a correct solution or not?

is there a way to create a "finite state machine-like" with a GUI?

--EDIT--

I have a class Controller that creates the GUI. After that is created I call the "class procedures" that should run the algorithm.

In the class I CONTROLLER of buttons and graphic objects static

static JButton btn1;
static JPanel panel1
static JButton btn2;

In the class PROCEDURES'm going to call the methods of the items listed above.

Example: When you can see Frame I need to check a particular variable, just change, I need to enable btn1 .. after you press btn1, I abiliare btn2, and so on ..

is correct then as a solution?

--- EDIT 2 ---

```
public class Controller extends JFrame {

    static JButton btn1;
    static JPanel panel1;
    static JButton btn2;

    public Controller() {       

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 1, 0, 0));

        //PANEL
        panel1 = new JPanel();      
        FlowLayout flowLayout_1 = (FlowLayout) panel_1.getLayout();
        flowLayout_1.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        panel_chkCom0.add(panel_1);
        btn1 = new JButton("BUTTON 1");     
        btnChk.setEnabled(false);
        btnChk.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
        panel_1.add(btn1);
        panel.add(panel1);

        //TODO

        //When I finish init myself, call my manager thread
        Thread t = new Thread(new SetupProcedure());
        t.start();
    }   
}



public class SetupProcedure implements Runnable {
    protected boolean btnChkIsPress = false;

    public void run(){ 
         SetupManager();
    }

    public void SetupManager() {

        final long POLLING_TIME = 600000;
        boolean isOff = true;

        long pollingTime = 0;
        //Check if it's on

        while(isOff){
            //SIMULATE READING FROM REGISTER
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                PWisOff = false;
                Controller.btn1.setEnabled(true);               
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }

        SetupController.btn1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                btnChkIsPress  = true;
            }
        });
        while(!btnChkIsPress){
            System.out.println("..wait..");
        }

        SetupController.btn2.setEnabled(true);

    ...OTHER...

    public String getResponseFromKernel(String request){
        String s = "Response";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: need to see your code first

Comment: Your question is rather subjective. It depends on how you've coded it. We can't judge a "correct" solution without more info.

Answer (score 1):

Make a data model **FiniteStateModel**, with listeners for events.
Maka a view **ViewFrame**, with normal non-static buttons, if needed dynamically added buttons or so.
The controller **Controller** can then wire the events to the view, and change so.

You will need `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { });` to be responsive and to switch to the AWT event queue.

---

***Schematically:***

For an easy GUI editor, creating JFrames and JPanels, you could try the NetBeans IDE.
(It really helps - concentrating on the business on hand, instead of the plumbing.)

```
/** Model. */
public class MessagesModel {
    ... controller.onMessageArrived(messageInfo); // Or via a more generic listener pattern.
}

/** View. */
public class ViewFrame extends JFrame {
    private App controller;
    private JButton btn1;

    public ViewFrame(App controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        ...
    }

    ... controller.markMessageRead(messageInfo);
}

/** Controller. */
public class App {
    private MessagesModel model;
    private ViewFrame view;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        model = new MessagesModel();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view = new ViewFrame(this);
                view.setVisible(true);
            });
    }

    /** Called by the model. */
    public void onMessageArrived(MessageInfo info) {
        view.setSomeAlert(info.title);
    }

    /** Called by the view. */
    public void markMessageRead(MessageInfo info) {
        model.markMessageRead(info);
    }
}
```

The model informs the controller of changes, and the controller calls a corresponding view method. This can be done by an event listener, or for simplicities sake, passing the controller to the model's constructor.

The advantage of MVC being that all the business logic / control flow is concisely written in the controller class.